# Firestore collection map to list

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I need to retrieve all documents from firestore collection with this:

```
  EventList<Event>testdata(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((data) => EventList<Event>(events: {
          data['date']: [
            Event(
                date: data['date'], title: data['name'], icon: Icon(
      Icons.block,
      color: Colors.red[200],
      size: 30,
    )),
          ]
        })).toList();
  }


  Stream<EventList<Event>> get caldendardata {
    return events.snapshots().map(testdata);
  }
```

but i get this error: `A value of type 'List<EventList<Event>>' can't be returned from the method 'testdata' because it has a return type of 'EventList<Event>'.`

The Firestore :[image]

I'm using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel) to add calendar to my app it requires the event on the calendar to be `{EventList<Event>? markedDatesMap}` .

**EventList form the package:**

```
class EventList<T> {
  Map<DateTime, List<T>> events;

  EventList({
    required this.events,
  });

  void add(DateTime date, T event) {
    final eventsOfDate = events[date];
    if (eventsOfDate == null)
      events[date] = [event];
    else
      eventsOfDate.add(event);
  }

  void addAll(DateTime date, List<T> events) {
    final eventsOfDate = this.events[date];
    if (eventsOfDate == null)
      this.events[date] = events;
    else
      eventsOfDate.addAll(events);
  }

  bool remove(DateTime date, T event) {
    final eventsOfDate = events[date];
    return eventsOfDate != null ? eventsOfDate.remove(event) : false;
  }

  List<T> removeAll(DateTime date) {
    return events.remove(date) ?? [];
  }

  void clear() {
    events.clear();
  }

  List<T> getEvents(DateTime date) {
    return events[date] ?? [];
  }
}
```

**Event form the package:**

```
class Event implements EventInterface {
  final DateTime date;
  final String? title;
  final Widget? icon;
  final Widget? dot;
  final int? id;
  Event({
    this.id,
    required this.date,
    this.title,
    this.icon,
    this.dot,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    return this.date == other.date &&
        this.title == other.title &&
        this.icon == other.icon &&
        this.dot == other.dot &&
        this.id == other.id;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(date, title, icon, id);

  @override
  DateTime getDate() {
    return date;
  }

  @override
  int? getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @override
  Widget? getDot() {
    return dot;
  }

  @override
  Widget? getIcon() {
    return icon;
  }

  @override
  String? getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
}

abstract class EventInterface {
  DateTime getDate();
  String? getTitle();
  Widget? getIcon();
  Widget? getDot();
  int? getId();
}
```

I would appreciate a little help here.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I cannot understand EventList. Like what is EventList? Or please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

`map` returns a `List`. That's why you have a `List<EventList>`.

I believe you are trying to flatten the list so that you instead have a single `EventList` with all of the events. One way to accomplish this is to use `fold`.

Here is an example that you should be able to apply to your code. One could paste this into [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/) to quickly see how it works:

```dart
class Event {
  const Event(this.id);

  final int id;
}

class EventList {
  const EventList({required this.events});

  final List<Event> events;
}

class FirebaseData {
  const FirebaseData(this.docs);

  final List<Event> docs;
}

void main() {
  // Simulating your data stream
  final FirebaseData snapshot = FirebaseData(List.generate(5, (index) => Event(index)));
  
  // What you are returning from your code currently
  final List<EventList> eventListList =
      snapshot.docs.map((data) => EventList(events: [data])).toList();

  // What you actually want to return from your code
  final EventList eventList = eventListList.fold(EventList(events: []),
      (previousValue, element) => EventList(events: previousValue.events..addAll(element.events)));

  print(eventList.events);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When performing `toList` you getting a `List<EventList<Event>>` each `EventList` with one event.
I think you want to get a `List<Map>` from Firestore to later build your class.

You can achieve that with a code like this.

```dart
EventList<Event>testdata(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
//Get all data
    final List<Map> eventListMap = snapshot.docs.map((data) => {
          data['date']: [
            Event(
                date: data['date'], title: data['name'], icon: Icon(
      Icons.block,
      color: Colors.red[200],
      size: 30,
    )),
          ]
        }).toList();

//Join to single Map, it should not contain repeated keys (date) as one of them would be lost
    final Map eventsMap = eventsData.fold({},(map1, map2) => map1..addAll(map2));

//Return your class
    return EventList<Event>(events: eventsMap);
  }


  Stream<EventList<Event>> get caldendardata {
    return events.snapshots().map(testdata);
  }
```

I did not try it and you can rename or change anything.